# product create programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I am just trying to add simple product pro grammatically in magento,and i tried the below code

```
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product(); 
// Build the product 
$product->setSku(8000); 
$product->setAttributeSetId('some_int_value_of_some_attribute'); 
$product->setTypeId('simple'); $product->setName('order1');  
$product->setCategoryIds(array(4)); # some cat id's, my is 7 
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, my is 1 (default frontend) 
$product->setDescription('Full description here'); 
$product->setShortDescription('Short description here'); 
$product->setPrice(39.99); # Set some price

# Custom created and assigned attributes 
$product->setHeight('500');
$product->setWidth('500');
$product->setDepth('2');
$product->setType('simple');    
//Default Magento attribute 
 $product->setWeight(4.0000); $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); $product->setStatus(1); $product->setTaxClassId(0); # My default tax class $product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 99 )); $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); try {
    $product->save(); } catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Handle the error }

try{
    $product_model = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');

    // Load product
    $_sku = "8000";
    $my_product_id  = $product_model->getIdBySku($_sku);
    $my_product     = $product_model->load(43);
    $qty_value = 1;

    // Add to cart 
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($my_product, array('qty' => $qty_value));
    $cart->save();
    print_r($cart->getItemsQty().PHP_EOL);
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    var_dump("working");  } catch(Exception $e){
    return $e->getMessage(); }
```

i am using magento version 1.9.0.1

but i am getting blank page without any error and product is not added in backed.

so, Can anybody help me to find easiest way to create simple product programmatically.

Comment: Can you please tell clearly what you want to achieve? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want to add simple products through php code in magento.

Comment: add error reporting code `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` in your file for find out exact errors.

Comment: i already tried this but still nothing happens.

Comment: Is that category exists?

Comment: can you please tell me, this code is a part of class or new separate file ?

Comment: iTS A NEW SEPERATE FILE.

Comment: did you include the mage file in top of file (`require_once('app/Mage.php');`) ? and use this code `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');` instead of `$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Product save depending on Attribute and store.
```

First, check `how many attribute are  required  for products`
Second,`You need to set those attribute value to products`
Third,

```
 set store 
 $product->setStore($storeId);
```

If you are doing this code using script then add `below code before start of product create code`

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

More details:-

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

http://www.codetweet.com/magento/create-simple-product-magento-programmatically/